# Why can not I add ID for ImageView in xml file

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, imageview

I've tried add ImageView in the new simple EmptyActivity project. And I can't add Id for ImageView in the xml file. I've got a message `<interface declaration>, <parcelable declaration>, AidlTokenType.import or AidlToken.package expected, got '@'`. I can add Id for Button and for TextView without problems.
Android Studio 1.5.1

[image]

Comment: did you try to clean the project?

Comment: @vasilis yes, I've tried clean my project

Comment: Looks like some weird bug, have you tried one of the AS 2.0 betas?

Comment: @ThomasKeller thank you for feedback, I found decision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I launched Android Studio on other notebook to compare settings. I opened **Preferences -> Editor -> Language Injections**. I don't know how it's happen, but my android studio has wrong Language Injection "xml:ImageView/@id". I deleted it. And now everything works as I want.

[image]

Comment: Solved my similar problem with @string resources